# Algorithm keystroke dynamics

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic, machine-learning, keyboard

I have a third party keyboard app who's algorithm I'm trying to understand from a key map data file I have. It monitors the way you tap on your keyboard and then it adjusts the tappable area behind the scenes so as to accept user input more accurately. I'm now trying to similarly mimick this keyboard concept for a small game I am making.

This is the tappable character map the keyboard app rendered:
[image]

Here's an example of a character map for the keyboard letter `V`

```json
{
"v" : 
{
    "characters" : [ "v" ],
    "feature-threshold-multiplier" : 1.0,
    "initial-scale-multiplier" : 1.0,
    "mean" : 
    {
        "dof" : 40,
        "mode" : [ 210.0367889404297, 138.3223266601562 ] 
    },
    "precision" : 
    {
        "dof" : 40,
        "mode" : 
        [
            0.003064915072172880,
            -0.0009184600203298032,
            -0.0009184600203298032, 
            0.006329041905701160
        ]
    },
    "prior-mean" : [ 207.0, 142.50 ],
    "prior-precision" : [ 0.004667554982006550, 0.0, 0.0, 0.004667554982006550 ]
}
}
```

**Question**

What I'm trying to figure out now is which part of the data set determines the size of the tappable area and which part determines the rotation.

**My findings**

Some things I have noticed which may help others in helping me understand what the keys and their values actually relate to:

1. I have found that `precision` -> `mode` contains two values which are always the same for every single character map.
2. I have noticed that there is a `dof` key for both the `mean` and
   `mode` array, and they are always the same.

So far a friend has been able to figure out what one of the key values mean which contribute to the positioning of each tappable key.

The `mean` -> `mode`contains the x and y position.
This link shows a code output rendering of the character dataset given.

http://codepen.io/martinlindhe/pen/yebpgO

You'll notice that the output matches the exact `positioning` of the tappable key map shown below.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess here but my bet is:

```
pos = 210.0367889404297, 138.3223266601562
```

is position (corner or center) and

```
 0.0030649150721728800,-0.0009184600203298032
-0.0009184600203298032, 0.0063290419057011600
```

are 2 x 2D basis vectors (so size and orientation of your tapping area) and `size = 40` (which more or less matches position). I see 2 possible layouts (row-major or column-major) but your data is symmetric so no way to tell which one it is as both are:

```
 u = 40 * ( 0.0030649150721728800,-0.0009184600203298032)
 v = 40 * (-0.0009184600203298032, 0.0063290419057011600)
```

As you did not provide any info about coordinate system and also the position does not match the image at all (you post most likely scaled image) I can not verify any of them. The only thing that is visible is `u` is `~2` times the size of `v` and as this is for a **V** key (I assume) then I see it like this (infered from all data you provided):

[image: V key layout]

as you can see the `u` vector is mirrored (god knows why).

To verify you should check/compare more than just single key. To get the scaling I would chose `W,Z,M,O` as they form almost a rectangle covering almost whole keyboard... And also check differently rotated keys to verify the weird mirroring.